# Pair statistics: alternative to two point correlation?

Tags: correlation

I am interested in knowing whether my data have close pairs. Closed in some properties. One way to do it is to find the distribution of say for example $F_{ij} = w_1(x_i-x_j)^2 + w_2(y_i-y_j)^2$, where ($x_i$,$y_i$) is a coordinate of the ith particle and w1 and w2 are the weights. Null hypothesis will be the distribution of $F_{ij}$ when data is randomised. Comparing to the null hypothesis I can tell how much my data is clustered. This is roughly the 2 point correlation study. Is there any alternative statistics tool to understand how much my data is intercorrelated or structured?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by weights here?